# UV islands of multiple meshes turn into lines or distort into other shapes

Tags: materials, uv, shaders, uv-image-editor

[image]

I am trying to select relevant meshes in order to pack their UV islands onto a single UV map, but some of meshes and their respective islands either turn into lines or glitch out of the preview window completely. How can I fix this?

Comment: Unwrap again correctly?

Comment: That's too ambiguous, all of those meshes are "wrapped correctly" but they fail to load the UV tiles in the material preview without first tabbing into edit mode.

Comment: It's hard to guess where it fails without the object, maybe share it?